# Integrating Watson Assistant (formely conversation) with Telegram/Facebook

Tags: node.js, telegram, ibm-watson, messenger, watson-assistant

I am confused about how to integrate my Watson bot on messaging platforms such as Facebook messenger. To build that bot, I used the Watson Conversation service and also used Bluemix cloudfoundry node.js app to expose it on the web. It works very well, but I just can't integrate it to platforms without the use of a third-party platform like stamplay. I don't really want to use third-party platforms to integrate my bots.

Anyone have any ideas? Maybe I can host my own bots on my Bluemix cloud platform? I just don't know how.

Comment: Seen this? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: yea, i checked that out, it did't work with me, i also used the example here too : 
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/05/bot-for-facebook-messenger-using-bluemix/
 and what i get on messenger when i message the bot is : 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /Ho</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You might want to check out this page because it contains many resources on how to build chatbots with Watson services: https://www.ibm.com/watson/how-to-build-a-chatbot/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i already have a bot up and running as a cloud foundry app on bluemix, it is just i am not sure how to integrate that app with slack, telegram or facebook messenger, i used a platform called "stamplay" and it is overpriced to start using in production, i am planning a production of some product and bot is a major part of my solution, i just don't know how can i manually integrate between the app (or the conversation service) and messaging platforms like (messenger,telegram , etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use some facilitators for this, like Node-red or NGROK.

- Use [Node-red](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/) to Integrate Watson Conversation with facebook easily.
- Use NGROK, Tanmay Bakshi teaches how to do that. Check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z58O5xU57WA).

With Node-RED you can create `functions`, and have a lot of options for Business rules for your application.

**Note:** I've built some open source basic example to Integrate Watson Assistant with [Telegram](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-telegram) *and* [Facebook](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook) using Node.js. You can follow the instructions or read the docs in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

This middleware plugin allows developers to easily integrate a Watson Conversation workspace with multiple social channels like Slack, Facebook, and Twilio. Customers can have simultaneous, independent conversations with a single workspace through different channels.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: i actually tried this one but for some reason i couldn't get it to work, it gave me back on messenger an error of can't GET / , i will go back to it later cause for sure i missed some configuration here or there, thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a starter application for this purpose. My example is for Slack and you easily use it by creating an slack API token. 
The starter is implemented in node-red and you just need to insert your API token and the rest is deployed automatically. I used Watson Conversation and  Natural Language Understanding.

One-Click-Deploy and more detailed description: 
https://github.com/BenediktKrueger/SlackBot-Starter-on-Bluemix

Comment: that is really good one too, thank you for sharing , i actually used the node-RED solution for a telegram bot .